# How to slidetoggle multiple divs?

Tags: java, jquery, function, toggle, slide

I'm having a little problem with the slideToggle code.

This is what I have (JQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#ava-esimene").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $("#ava-teine").removeClass("active"); 
            $("#ava-kolmas").removeClass("active");
            $("#teine-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
            $("#kolmas-button").slideUp('slow', function() {  
              $("#esimene-button").slideToggle(400);
            });
    });


    $("#ava-teine").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $("#ava-esimene").removeClass("active");
            $("#ava-kolmas").removeClass("active");
            $("#esimene-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
            $("#kolmaa-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
                $("#teine-button").slideToggle(400);
           });
    });

    $("ava-kolmas").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $("#ava-esimene").removeClass("active");
            $("#ava-teine").removeClass("active");
            $("#esimene-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
            $("#teine-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
                $("#teine-button").slideToggle(400);
                });
    });

});
```

Can anyone make it work please?

Comment: what problem are you experiencing ?

Comment: `$("ava-kolmas")` you missed the `#`.

Comment: Post your HTML Code - so we can provide you help

Comment: I fixed the $("#ava-kolmas") but it still won't start working.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#ava-esimene").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("#ava-teine").removeClass("active"); 
    $("#ava-kolmas").removeClass("active");
    $("#teine-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
    $("#kolmas-button").slideUp('slow', function() {  
      $("#esimene-button").slideToggle(400);
    });
});


 $("#ava-teine").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("#ava-esimene").removeClass("active");
    $("#ava-kolmas").removeClass("active");
    $("#esimene-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
    $("#kolmaa-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $("#teine-button").slideToggle(400);
   });
 });

  $("#ava-kolmas").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("#ava-esimene").removeClass("active");
    $("#ava-teine").removeClass("active");
    $("#esimene-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
    $("#teine-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $("#teine-button").slideToggle(400);
        });
 });
```

You forget the # before ava-kolmas

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ava-esimene").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("#ava-teine").removeClass("active"); 
    $("#ava-kolmas").removeClass("active");
    $("#teine-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $("#kolmas-button").slideUp('slow', function() {  
            $("#esimene-button").slideToggle(400);
        });
    })});


$("#ava-teine").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("#ava-esimene").removeClass("active");
    $("#ava-kolmas").removeClass("active");
    $("#esimene-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $("#kolmaa-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
            $("#teine-button").slideToggle(400);
        });
    })});

    $("#ava-kolmas").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $("#ava-esimene").removeClass("active");
        $("#ava-teine").removeClass("active");
        $("#esimene-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
            $("#teine-button").slideUp('slow', function() {
                $("#kolmas-button").slideToggle(400);
            });
        });

    })
});
```

you miss configured the closings of your function try this